# Ableton Live - Monitor automation or Midi Mapping

Tags: midi, ableton-live, live

I'm trying to automate the monitor for a track in Ableton Live 10. I couldn't find automation for monitoring so I tried to use Midi mappings (with software Midi driver). The problem comes when I can't map each button of the monitor options, I mean, I can map only one Midi note to the entire monitor control (in, auto, off) and when the Midi note is triggered, the monitor control will just hop to the next button. For example:

1. Monitor is set to IN for the track.
2. My intention is now to set monitor OFF, so I press the Midi note already mapped.
3. Monitor will set to AUTO instead of setting to OFF because AUTO is the next button after IN.

How can I map a note to monitor control so I can choose if turning monitor On or Off?
Is there an automation option for this maybe?

I need to alternate between monitor in/off because I'm using multiple tracks with Looper plugin and I need to select which tracks will receive input from my instrument while keeping output sound on because looper will keep sending audio.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

I know about a control surface called ClyphX and I've worked with it and it would be really easy to achieve what I'm looking for using it but I'm trying to do everything I can in a native way in Ableton.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Monitoring does not have any effect on the recording. It only feeds back what is being recorded. Instead, you can automatize the arming of tracks by right clicking the rec button, select MIDI/Key Map and use a key/controller for each track.

Alternatively, you could use an Instrument Rack on a single channel that you fill with instances of Looper and use the Chain function to switch between instances.